# Reactjs : Can someone please elaborate this line to me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read this line over [here](https://github.com/christiannwamba/react-pusher-getting-started/blob/master/src/App.js)

```html
this.setState({ chats: [...this.state.chats, data], test: '' });
```

I think we are saving chats array in the state, ...this.state.chat refers to the original chat variable and then I am lost

Comment: `chats: [...this.state.chats, data]` is exactly same as `chats: this.state.chats.concat(data)`

Comment: `...` is known as spread operator. Which creates a copy of an array without retaining reference to the original array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code updates two state properies:

1. `chats` - create a new array from the previous `chats` and the new `data` using [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#A_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays).
2. `test` - update test to an empty string. This is a typo in the original code, and should have been `text`.

**Spread example:**

```js
const chats = [1, 2, 3];
const data = 4;
const newChats = [...chats, data];

console.log(newChats);
```

However, since state is asynchronous, it's better to use the the [updater callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to update the state, because:

> Both prevState and props received by the updater function are
>   guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly
>   merged with prevState.

**Update Example:**

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ chats: [...prevState.chats, data], test: '' }));
```

Comment: why is test: '' there at the end. Your original snippet didnt refer to test

Comment: My snippet explained the how the spread works. It didn't include `setState()` at all. The second part explains that it's better to use an updater function, and I've used your original setState.

Comment: I am sorry I am not trying to argue with you but i am just asking what does that , test: ' ' do

Comment: @S.Iqbal - I was not aware that the `test` was what bothering you. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I think the original writer of the code misspelled text to test and that created the confusion

Comment: Yep, you're right. The original state is `    this.state = {
      text: '',
      username: '',
      chats: []
    };`

Answer (score 0):

Here **state consist of array of chats**, they are **appending** new chat object stored in data variable to state.

```
this.state = {
      text: '',
      username: '',
      chats: []
    };
  }
```

Therefore data gets added to chat array at the end of chat array present in state. It is increasing the state chat array size.

```
this.setState({ chats: [...this.state.chats, data], test: '' });
```

Hope your doubt is cleared.

Comment: I dont understand why do we need this , test: ''

Comment: @S.Iqbal that is a typo, instead of 'text', it is written as 'test'.

Comment: I figured from the other post and looking back at the code. Thanks